# React Native Google Sign In null values in userdata

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I'm using this [module](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin) to login with google. All config with firebase are ok and the login is working, but today I faced something strange.

In login flow, first google asks permission to access user data (from designed scopes) when this method is called:

```
const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
```

then a json is returned with user info and other data.

But today, except by email, my data returned with null values:

```
{...other data "user": {"email": "myemail@gmail.com", "familyName": null, "givenName": null, , "name": null, "photo": null}}
```

This is an issue because this data is used in the API and the mobile application. This worries me because it could happen to a client and it would be a huge inconvenience.

Some useful info:
This issue begins today;
This happens with my email only;
I tried to revoke application login permission on google accounts config, no success;
A full wipe on mobile app also don't works;

google requested scopes:

> userinfo.profile
>
> userinfo.email

Anyone faced this problem before?

Feel free to ask if you need more information.
Thanks in advance.